# How to find the minimum difference between dates in two different columns with some condition

Tags: sql, r

I have two columns in two different tables of date like below

```
A: response table:
key    response_date 
1      2013/01/01
1      2015/12/01
2      2016/02/01
3      2016/08/01
3      2016/09/01

B: Call table
key  attempt  call_date
1    1        2014/11/20
1    2        2015/09/01
2    3        2016/01/01
2    4        2016/03/01
2    5        2016/10/15
3    6        2016/03/01
3    7        2016/07/01
```

There would be only one response for every single call when the key in call table is matched to key in response table. I want to find the time to the response. The response happens after a call and it should be the most recent response after that call. For example for key 1, there are two calls on 2014/11/20 and 2015/09/01 and also two different response on 2013/01/01 and 2015/12/01. The  2015/12/01 is response date of call on 2015/09/01 not call on 2014/11/20 because it is closer to call on  2015/09/01. Then there is no response to call on  2013/01/01 and time_diff=0.

For key 2, there is no response for call attemps 4 and 5.

For key 3 attempt 6, we could see two response with key=3 but they are closer call attempt 7. So there is no repsonse to attemp 6 and time_diff=0 and time_diff for attempt 7 is days between (2016/07/01,2016/08/01) which is the most recent response after attempt 7.

```
key  attempt  time_diff
1    1        0
1    2        days between(2015/09/01,2015/12/01)
2    3        days between(2016/01/01,2016/02/01)
2    4        0
2    5        0
3    6        0
3    7        days between(2016/07/01,2016/08/01)
```

any response or hint in sql or R would be appreciated.

Comment: Your expected outcome is not clear to me: Take `key=1, activity=1` from your second dataset. Then `date_A=2015/12/01` from your first dataset is after `date_B=2014/11/20` for `key=1`, so why do you have `time_diff=0` in your expected outcome?

Comment: Similarly for `key=3, activity=6`: `date_A=2016/08/01 > date_B=2016/03/01`. Why `time_diff=0` for this entry? I also don't understand how you merge. For example, for `key=1, activity=1` I expect *two* entries in your expected outcome, because you have *two* entries for `date_A`. Why do you only keep one?

Comment: for key=1, activity=1 from your second dataset which date_A=2015/12/01, from first dataset we have 2015/12/01 and 2013/01/01. only  2015/12/01 is after date_B=2014/11/20 but there is another data_B=2015/09/01 for key 1 which is more recent compare to date_B=2014/11/20. so the time_diff for activity 1 is 0 and time diff for activity 2 =days between(2015/09/01,2015/12/01)

Comment: I'm not following you. Why not *two* entries for `key=1, activity=1`? You've go *two* dates in `date_A` that match. You don't mention anywhere that you discard entries. Please take a look at my solution attempt below, which is incomplete and not yet consistent with what you want. Perhaps you can clarify below.

Comment: I have updated the question. hope it is clear and you could help me.

Comment: *"Then there is no response to call on 2013/01/01 and time_diff=0."* But the `2013/01/01` call *is* a response call (it's from your response table B). Still not following...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below `R` solution helps!

```r
library(dplyr)

response_table$response_date <- as.Date(response_table$response_date)
call_table$call_date <- as.Date(call_table$call_date)

call_table %>%
  left_join(response_table, by = "key") %>%
  mutate(date_diff = as.numeric(response_date - call_date)) %>%
  filter(date_diff > 0) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  filter(which.min(date_diff) == row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(time_diff = paste0('days between(',call_date,',',response_date,')')) %>%
  right_join(call_table, by = c("key", "attempt")) %>%
  select(key, attempt, time_diff) %>%
  replace_na(list(time_diff='0'))
```

Output is:

```
    key attempt time_diff                                                   
1     1       1 0                                  
2     1       2 days between(2015-09-01,2015-12-01)
3     2       3 days between(2016-01-01,2016-02-01)
4     2       4 0                                  
5     2       5 0                                  
6     3       6 0                                  
7     3       7 days between(2016-07-01,2016-08-01)
```

Sample data:

```
response_table <- structure(list(key = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), response_date = c("2013/01/01", 
"2015/12/01", "2016/02/01", "2016/08/01", "2016/09/01")), .Names = c("key", 
"response_date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))

call_table <- structure(list(key = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), attempt = 1:7, 
    call_date = c("2014/11/20", "2015/09/01", "2016/01/01", "2016/03/01", 
    "2016/10/15", "2016/03/01", "2016/07/01")), .Names = c("key", 
"attempt", "call_date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the dialect of SQL, so I wrote this for SQL Server. It would probably require a bit of syntax adjustment to make it work in another DBMS, but here's a general idea that will get you there:

```
SELECT 
    b.[key]         AS  [key],
    b.activity      AS  activity,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, a.date_A, b.date_B) = c.max_time 
    THEN C.max_time
    ELSE 0 END      
                    AS time_diff
FROM
    b
JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
        b.[key]                                 AS  [key],
        MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, a.date_A, b.date_B))  AS  max_time
    FROM
        a
    JOIN
        b 
    ON  
        a.[key] =  b.[key]
    GROUP BY 
        b.[key]
    ) AS c
ON
    b.[key] = c.[key]
JOIN
    a
ON
    b.[key] = a.[key]
```

Comment: I have tried your approach and it does not work. I revisited the problem. Your approach does not consider the most recent response after each call. like the one that happens for key 1, call 1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand (nor can reproduce) the logic behind your expected outcome.

Based on your expected outcome notation, this is what I would *expect* for the outcome.

```
key  activity time_diff
1    1        days between(2014/11/20,2015/12/01)
1    2        days between(2015/09/01,2015/12/01)
2    3        days between(2016/01/01,2016/02/01)
2    4        0
2    5        0
3    6        days between(2016/03/01,2016/08/01)
3    7        days between(2016/07/01,2016/08/01)
```

Perhaps you can explain, why the entries `key=1,activity=1` and `key=3,activity=6` have `time_diff=0` in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me explain my question again here: in your result

Comment: @Sajjad I've edited my solution attempt to include the expected outcome based on what I understood. Perhaps you can clarify in the comments here why this is incorrect.

Comment: entries key=1,activity=1 has time_diff=0 because the call_date=2014/11/20 and there is another call after that for key=1 on 2015/09/01 which is closer to the response date 2015/12/01. So there is no response to first call on 2014/11/20 . Thanks again. by the way I do not see your new code

Comment: @Sajjad No, I'm sorry, that makes no sense to me. Take `key=2,activity=3`: By your reasoning, this should give `time_diff=0` because `date_B=2016/03/01` from `key=2,activity=4` is closer to `date_A=2016/02/01`. So according to your rules, you would have a non-zero entry for `key=2,activity=4`. But in your expected outcome that's not the case. Can you please check.

Comment: @Sajjad PS. I removed my solution attempt, because I'm less and less sure about your logic behind the expected outcome.